# Custom Upload.aspx for Content Types in 2013

Tags: content-type, forms-authentication, spservices

I'm trying to create an Upload.aspx and EditForm.aspx for a custom content type on my site in SharePoint Designer 2013. I'm adding cascading columns functionality using SPServices. My problem is that the custom content type doesn't use the form I specify. My code works great for the "Document" content type. I created some edit forms at the library level and I pasted their URL's next to the "Forms" where "Click to add text" was. What am I doing wrong here?

[image: Content Type Forms]